# PHP + MySQL problems :(

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am havin trouble with this code:

```
if ($_GET['offline']) {$extranet = $_GET['offline'];} else {$extranet = $online;}
$sql = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE tbl_system SET value = '$extranet' WHERE property = 'extranet'");
echo $_GET['offline'];
echo $extranet;
echo $online;
```

In the database, the value  of the field where the property = extranet is 1.
Results of echo:

```
$_GET['offline'] = 0 
$extranet        = 1
$online          = 1
```

Now, obviously, something's wrong here.

The URL to give this GET is: `?app=admincp&offline=0`, so `$_GET['offline']` is not the problem.

The problem must lie in the if statement, but I can't figure it out,

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there code that actually sets the value of extranet?
I would rewrite this to be more clear. Make sure you initialize your variables properly, print them out in one nice string before any conditions and a similar string after all is done and update the post. Then we will be more able to help you.

Jacob

Comment: If I am reading this right, offline is set to 0, extranet is set to the value of $online which starts at 1

Comment: yep, I add that (sanitation) once i can guarantee that the raw code is working :)
ty Koning baard, @ TJT, yep :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_GET['offline'] is 0, and 0 evaluates to false, so the statement goes right. if you want to check whether offline is passed as an argument you have to use `isset()`

```
if (!isset($_GET['offline'])) {$extranet = $_GET['offline'];} else {$extranet = $online;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($_GET['offline'])
```

That will return false because the string "0" evaluates to false in PHP, so the if statement's condition can never evaluate to true. Use [`isset`](http://www.php.net/isset) or [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists) instead. e.g.:

```
if (isset($_GET['offline'])) { ... }
```

or:

```
if (array_key_exists('offline',$_GET)) { ... }
```

In your case, you'll want to know whether or not the value is exactly the string zero "0". I would recommend using [strcmp](http://www.php.net/strcmp):

```
if (strcmp($_GET['offline'],"0") === 0) {
    $extranet = $_GET['offline'];
} else {
    $extranet = $online;
}
$sql = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE tbl_system SET value = '$extranet' WHERE property = 'extranet'");
echo $_GET['offline'];
echo $extranet;
echo $online;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yikes! In addition to karim's comment- sanitize your inputs! You're taking a URL parameter and putting it directly into an SQL query. A url of

```
?app=admincp&offline=';DROP table tbl_system;--
```

Would ruin you!

Comment: yep, I add that once i can guarantee that the raw code is working :)

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET['offline']` is zero in the URL you provide, so `if($_GET['offline'])` and everything in that block will never be hit.  Use `isset()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strcmp($_GET['offline'],"0") === 0) {
    $extranet = $_GET['offline'];
} else {
    $extranet = $online;
}
```

This will throw an error in the case that $_GET['offline'] is not set, better to use `!isset($_GET['offline'])`